# Is it not possible to add instance and shared features to a pre-existing FCI?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, failover-cluster-instance

I'm looking at a sql server fci that has the database engine installed. My task is to add the full text search service and integration services.

I'm exploring how to do this when I came across this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/install/create-a-new-sql-server-failover-cluster-setup?view=sql-server-ver16#to-install-a-new--failover-cluster-instance-using-integrated-install-with-add-node

> You cannot add features to a failover cluster instance after creation.

Has anyone added features to an fci post installation and do you know whether the above quote is true for instance level and shared feature? For example full text is an instance level feature whereas integration services is a shared feature.

I'm not sure it is acceptable to install new fci as that would require migration so hoping to get some advise here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, it's not possible to add features to an existing FCI instance. Even if you can do it, your SQL Server will be in an unsupported state, which is bad for a production database. So my suggestion is, tell your boss it's not possible and you guys have to rebuild the cluster.

Comment: Ssis for example is a shared feature for example so I was hoping that may be possible to install